According to Dwaita Vedanta, What Happens to Lord Mukhyaprana When He Becomes Lord Brahma?
According to Dvaita Vedanta, Shri Madhvacharya is Lord Mukhyaprana who is the highest Jiva Atma, even higher than Lord Brahma who is the other son of Lord Narayana. Dvaita Vedantins believe that Lord Mukhyaprana will become the next Lord Brahma. Does that mean Lord Mukhyaprana is scheduled to lose his Jivottamma status, or will we always have that status regardless.
Please let me know.

Nevermind. I found my answer here: https://www.facebook.com/photo?fbid=276771765779303&set=what-is-ruju-and-rujutva-rujutvaseveral-mentions-in-various-puranas-and-scriptur
